# WebApproot in Spring

Tags: xml, spring

I get this error message

> [ SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Web app root system property already set to different value: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\jaanlai\Documents\NetBeansProjects\absSovellus\build\web] instead of [C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\keycard2\build\web] - Choose unique values for the 'webAppRootKey' context-param in your web.xml files!

It's odd, because I don't have any webAppRootKey defined in my files. What is it?

Comment: See http://drglennn.blogspot.com/2008/08/problems-with-webapproot-system.html and http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-32873.html for solutions

Answer (score 68):

The `webAppRootKey` is a context parameter that Spring uses in a couple of places. In this case, it's being used by the `Log4jWebConfigurer`. It exposes the webapp root as a system property that can be used in log4j configuration files, something like this:

```
log4j.appender.testfile.File=${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/testlog.log
```

You would use this if you, for some reason, wanted to locate your logs relative to your webapp root.

The problem that you're running into is that some containers (notably Tomcat) don't maintain a per-webapp mapping of system properties.  When you don't specify a `webAppRootKey`, Spring defaults it to `webapp.root`.  Since you're running two apps in the same container, the second app you're trying to start up sees that the `webAppRootKey` is already set (via the default), and throws an error.  Otherwise, the `webAppRootKey` would be set incorrectly, and you could end up with logs from one webapp in another webapp.

You can specify a different `webAppRootKey` using context parameters in your `web.xml` like so:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webapp.root.one</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And

```
log4j.appender.testfile.File=${webapp.root.one}/WEB-INF/testlog.log
```

in your log4j. This should take care of the conflict.

Comment: Note we had the same problem with Websphere v8, and your solution fixed the issue. (don't want others to think the problem is only with Tomcat)

Comment: I also had this problem on JBoss, and your solution worked for me.

Comment: @MichaelLucas Did the issue on Websphere v8 affect anything besides logging?

Comment: @indybee  ... no I don't think so. It was a long time ago so hard to remember, but I think it only affected log4j.

Answer (score 52):

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

...

This solved the problem for me. Credit to:-
http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-32873.html

Comment: nice, I was going to define a property in maven and then filter web.xml. But then it wouldn't work in development where I use mongrel eclipse plugin to start tomcat with my webapps.

Comment: 63 v 52 v 18 v alsoRans, on q of 38, as of 20191114.

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you have several webapps with default `Log4jConfigListener` configuration in your application server.

Default behaviour for `Log4jConfigurationListener` is to expose webapp root as a system property named `webapp.root`, to allow you to use it when specifying log file locations. However, if system property with the same name already exists, it throws an exception.

You can either configure per-application names for that system property using `<context-param>` named `webAppRootKey`, or disable exposing of the system property by setting `Log4jConfigListener`'s `<init-param>` named `log4jExposeWebAppRoot` to `false`.

**See also:**

- [`Log4jWebConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html)

Comment: Can this prevent application to run, giving 404 - the requested source is not available?

Comment: @michaeljackson4ever: I guess no. After all, you can always check it by removing `Log4jConfigListener`.

Comment: I'm having the problem that the application does not run. Setting the root key did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else has done the above without getting rid of the problem:

Our webapp had the webAppRootKey set correctly, but I still got the exception above. Restarting Glassfish and redeploying the same war-file worked, go figure.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `logback` instead of `log4j` and get the same error, this solves it:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>logbackExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```